# Continuous Kibana Transform is not updated as source index and has one checkpoint since creation

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, transform

Kibana 7.7.1

I am creating a transform to do an aggregation on a true/false field per user's set of data.

on the source index document can be updated with updated status (true/false) and also new data are coming. Source index frequency of change can be more than 1 hour.
I am creating Transform sync on `@timestamp`
I created as many transforms as i can with all frequency and sync/delay possibilities and it never updated after creation and has only one checkpoint of creation.

I am not sure what am I doing wrong
here is the transform API I used

```html
PUT _transform/mytransform
{
  "source": {
    "index": [
      "mysource"
    ],
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "match_all": {}
          }
        ],
        "filter": [
          {
            "match_phrase": {
              "myflag": false
            }
          },
          {
            "range": {
              "mydate": {
                "lt": "now"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "should": [],
        "must_not": []
      }
    }
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "mydest"
  },
  "frequency": "1h",
  "sync": {
    "time": {
      "field": "@timestamp",
      "delay": "24h"
    }
  },
  "pivot": {
    "group_by": {
      "userID.keyword": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "userID.keyword"
        }
      }
    },
    "aggregations": {
      "userDocID.keyword.value_count": {
        "value_count": {
          "field": "userDocID.keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
  }
```

Comment: Do you mind sharing your transform definition?

Comment: I updated the post with definition, appreciate your input